# Bubbling up newer records

Tags: lucene

Is it possible to bubble up newer records in lucene search results?
ie.I want Lucene to give a higher score to records which are closer to today's date.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to give more details on what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 1):

I have only used Lucene through Solr, but it has great support arbitrary document boosted according to a [user-supplied function](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#head-fc54f81a2fe06839c65b8216a8c8b37fbf201548).

In your case, I'd use something like:

```
recip(rord(created_when),1,1000,500)
```

As a boost function. I realise this doesn't answer your specifically Lucene question, but if you can do it with a Solr QueryHandler, you can definitely do it in a Lucene app!